# user controller unit conversion

Tags: mysql

I am building an on-line store and would like to provide the ability to specify various measurements for products. Things like width/height and weight.

Taking width as an example, they would enter a value and then select `mm, cm, m` etc.

The application would then convert it to the same base unit, say mm to make it easy to use through out the application.

What would be a good schema for doing this type of thing? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
id     name     factor
1      mm       1
2      cm       0.1
3      m        0.001
...
```

I could then do $userValue / $factor = $normalised. This would probably require a join table with something along the lines of:

```
id name
1  length
2  weight
...
```

Is this the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out how the UNIX `units` function works.  It's driven by a data file and hopefully gets around some of the nasty issues.

http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/units.1.php

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do to avoid floating point is *highly* advised. If you store 0.001 in the database as a float you might end up with an actual value of 0.00099999999982713 which can lead to tiny yet irritating deviations from what you intend.

It would be much better to express these as an integer value of some "minimal" unit you're willing to work with. For instance, micrometers, and convert all values to this equivalent measure. This is what's done for currency in most systems to avoid brutal rounding errors.